# Valgrind App crash due to Kernel panic Error while accessing external DDR memory

Tags: memory-leaks, linux-kernel, arm, valgrind, dmalloc

I am running one application on linux with valgrind on my custom hardware ARM architecture board, which access external DDR memory (not present on board) causing application to crash with following reason

Bad mode in Error handler detected on CPU3. code 0xbf000002 -- SError
Kernel Panic- not synching bad mode

I dont see this problem when application tries to access on board local DDR memory.I dont see same problem with other memory leak tools like dmalloc or address sanitizer.
is this there any known problem and solution for this issue ?

not sure if I have given complete info let me know if you need more details.

Thanks in advance for you time & effort.

I was using valgrind memcheck tool to report memory leak issues from my application.

Comment: From the OS perspective, is there any difference between local and external memory?

Comment: I don't think so, Address ranges only differs for both memories. For external memory we have controller in between (controller is simple in functionality), no sure could that cause anything (cannot overrule) but not having problem with other mem leak tools

Comment: I think your best hope is to log a bug on the kde bugzilla with a log containing verbose (-v -v -v -v) and debug (-d -d -d -d) and syscalls (--trace-syscalls=yes).

Comment: Ok Paul. I will collect logs and check on kde bugZilla